# How can I solve this system of equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratic-forms

Here is a system of equations:

$$\begin{cases}
x^2 + 10y = 41\\
y^2-2z = 23\\
z^2-6x = 17
\end{cases} $$

What's the value of $x$ and $y$ and $z$?

Comment: Probably the reason someone voted to close this is that it's phrased in a manner appropriate to assigning homework.  Can you say what your thoughts on this are?

Comment: The proper way to solve such a problem is to find symmetric combinations of the variables which are solutions to quadratic equations and then to repeat this until the question is solved. Of course it much easier just the close the thing, and remain in ignorance.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: there has been a great deal of discussion about the PSQ (problem statement question) issue on [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/search?q=PSQ). If you have issues with people closing questions, you should bring it up on meta, not in comments, where it will get relatively little exposure.

Comment: @robjohn I wont do that for two reasons 1)I spend my time doing mathematics. 2) I dont want to become one of what I refer to as "those idiots on meta".

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: in any case, this subject is off-topic for a comment to a question on main.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: I am talking about the topic of which questions should be closed. That belongs on meta, not main.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: You seem to want to discuss it on main, that doesn't sound like spending your time doing mathematics. All I am saying is that if you are going to discuss it, please use the proper forum.

Comment: Can write a system of quadratic equations in two variables and the two equations?

Comment: Are $x, y, z$ integers, real numbers, rationals??

Answer (score 0):

It is straightforward to determine the solutions over $\mathbb{C}$. We obtain indeed a polynomial of degree $8$, hence $8$ complex roots. More precisely, we obtain
$$
x=\frac{z^2 - 17}{6},\; y=\frac{ - z^4 + 34z^2 + 1187}{360},
$$
where $z$ is a root of the polynomial
$$
t^8 - 68t^6 - 1218t^4 + 37516t^2 - 837431.
$$
This may not look nice, but it is a valid answer.

Is it possible that the system has a typo ? If you, say, consider the equations
\begin{align*}
x^2+10y & = 41, \\
y^2-2z & = 32, \\
z^2-6x & = 10,
\end{align*}
then $(x,y,z)=(9,-4,-8)$ is a nice solution.

Comment: Do you mean you completed the problem as is? Or, you completed the problem with your alterations?

Comment: @Vincent No, I completed the problem given in the question. But I think, the OP made a typo. Did you just downvote for this misunderstanding ?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this is with substitution.

$$y = \frac{41-x^2}{10}$$

$$z = \frac{20-y^2}{-2}$$

Now plug this $z$ into the third equation. This gives you an equation in terms of $x$ and $y$. Substitute the above equation into $y$, and you have a polynomial in $x$. Solve the polynomial equation and find $x$.

Comment: This is what I tried doing earlier when this problem was posted. It did not work out for me. You end up with $x^8$ and it gets ugly. Perhaps, I had an algebraic mistake. Did you complete the problem using this method and it worked?

Comment: I double checked, you end up with this:
$\left(\large\frac{41-x^2}{10}\right)^4-10\left(\large\frac{41-x^2}{10}\right)^2-6x=-83$  

How did you solve this?

Comment: No I didn't complete the problem. It's the best way I could think of to find a solution, and there might not be a nice solution either. Perhaps some root finding techniques could help with the polynomial? For instance the rational root theorem would apply here.